# Any options to build your own java based youtube html5 video player for android?

Tags: java, android

I need to build a Video Player in android that can play
youtube HTML5 videos (www.youtube.com/html5)  also be able
to embed the player within an android app I build.

The tablets I am building this app for cannot use flash at all
(this is why I need to build my own).

This would end up being a kids app, so I really only want to give
them 4 options on the player: play, reply, pause, exit

I am still a little confused as to would I be playing this embed
video in my custom app (with custom video player i make) using rtsp://
or a m.youtube.com H.264

Thanks in advance, all help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These projects from GIthub might get you started.

[vivdub / AndroidMediaplayer](https://github.com/vivdub/AndroidMediaplayer)

[joelbinn / media-player](https://github.com/joelbinn/media-player)

[lxz2003 / mediaplayer](https://github.com/lxz2003/mediaplayer)